# Unity 3D Particle System works in editor but not build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, particle-system

I've been making a manager for decals on walls that conforms to the face by normals and it mainly consists of a particle system that uses .emit to put out a single particle (in this case the decal) at the point and normal vector of a collision that can be passed to the method. It works beautifully in the editor without any problems from 1 particle to 1000 at any point, but as soon as I try to open up a build of the game the blood doesn't appear at all. I've tried switching shaders, double sided shaders, and all of the options I can think of in the inspector, but since the particles are emitted through code I don't really use any of the modules so all I can extensively check are renderer and main settings. I also tried putting the system directly in front of camera as a child, but no luck. I have included screenshots below of the system's settings and a picture of the decals working in the editor and code below.

I've been stumped for a while now by this and I would really appreciate to hear what you guys think can help me out. Thank you in advance!

[blood](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgKtj.jpg)

[settings1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keQ8q.png)

[settings2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjKw6.png)

```
private ParticleSystem ps;

void Start()
{

    ps = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

}

public void SpawnBlood(Vector3 pos, Vector3 normals)
{

    float x = normals.x * .01f;
    float y = normals.y * .01f;
    float z = normals.z * .01f;
    // moving position away from wall

    var emitParams = new ParticleSystem.EmitParams();
    emitParams.position = pos + new Vector3(x, y, z);
    emitParams.rotation3D = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, normals).eulerAngles;

    ps.Emit(emitParams, 1);
    //Debug.Log(normals);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the variable .isStatic only working in editor.